# Testing local scoped object with mockito without refactoring

Tags: java, junit, mocking, junit4, mockito

Say I have the following code:

```
public class ClassToTest
{
    AnotherClass anotherClass;

    public void methodToTest( int x, int y )
    {
        int z = x + y
        anotherClass.receiveSomething( z );
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public void receiveSomething( int z ) {.. do something.. }  
}
```

I want to make assertion on the value of the variable z. How do I do this without refactoring? Variables x, y, and z could be some other Java class types, and I just used "int" for simplicity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write the following. *Of course dependency injection and test method might change depending on your current implementation and/or your test scenarios.*

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassToTestTest {

    @Mock AnotherClass anotherClass;
    @InjectMocks ClassToTest classToTest;

    @Test public void ensure_that_value___Z___is_passed_to___AnotherClass() {
        classToTest.methodToTest(1, 2);

        verify(anotherClass).receiveSomething(eq(3));
    }
}
```

*Written with Mockito 1.9.5-rc1 in mind.*

Also instead of using the `eq` matcher you can instead use an `ArgumentCaptor`, which will capture values or value references (in case of objects). You'll be able to perform additional assertions on the captured value(s). For example using Truth or FEST-Assert.

This could look like :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClassToTestTest {

    ...
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<List<Z>> listCaptor

    @Test public void ensure_that_list_with_value___Z___is_passed_to___AnotherClass() {
        // given

        // when
        ...

        // then
        verify(anotherClass).receiveList(listCaptor.capture());
        assertThat(listCaptor.getValue()).contains(Z);
    }
}
```

Cheers,

Comment: thanks. What about if I want to inspect z's properties if z is of some java class? Say, I might have some logic and not just a simple comparison.

Comment: @supertonsky Yes I thought I missed that in the first answer, I just edited it to fill in the missing stuff about specific assertions :)